# How can i download a file from the internet and apply its path to MUI_PAGE_LICENSE macro?

Tags: nsis

newbie here

i'm currently trying to figure out how to assign a downloaded file's path to MUI_PAGE_LICENSE macro like this:

`!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE blah_txt_location`

i know that i can do `inetc::get /SILENT "online file location" "install location" /end` to get the file downloaded - but my problem is that `!insertmacro` is ran during compile time and downloading the file is done during run time (i think im correct with that - please tell me if not)

So how can i go about doing this?

Edit: Turns out anders code did work however adding `OutFile "App.exe"` will crash it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign it directly, you have to load it dynamically:

```
!include MUI2.nsh

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW DelayLoadLicenseFile
!tempfile dummylicense
!appendfile "${dummylicense}" "$\n"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${dummylicense}"
!delfile "${dummylicense}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function DelayLoadLicenseFile
SendMessage $mui.Licensepage.LicenseText ${EM_LIMITTEXT} -1 ""
FileOpen $1 "$PluginsDir\license.txt" R
${If} $1 P<> 0
    FileSeek $1 0 END $2
    FileSeek $1 0 SET
    System::Call '*(&m$2)p.r3'
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::ReadFile(p$1,p$3,i$2,*i,p0)'
    System::Call 'USER32::SendMessageA(p$mui.Licensepage.LicenseText,i${WM_SETTEXT},p0,p$3)'
    System::Free $3
    FileClose $1
#${Else}
#   MessageBox mb_iconStop "blah blah license!"
#   Quit
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
InitPluginsDir
inetc::get /SILENT "http://example.com/license.txt" "$PluginsDir\license.txt" /end
Pop $0
Messagebox mb_ok Debug:$0
FunctionEnd
```

You probably don't want to leave the default license empty though, the download might fail if the user is not online or the server is down. If you want to load a RTF file you might have to [stream it in](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=231547)...

Comment: Hay thanks for the quick response! - unfortunately the example you've provided doesn't seem to work (i have added nessecary components like Name, OutFile etc..).
The only error it produced was `invalid script: no sections specified` 
so i fixed that by adding an empty section at the very bottom however after that no errors are produced, the liscense page is empty and no file is downloaded.
The current website im using is https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt which is just a simple txt file so im sure it isn't that.

Comment: Works fine for me. Which version of NSIS are you using? While the license page is open, check `%temp%\ns*` to make sure the license has downloaded...

Comment: Currently i'm using `MakeNSIS v3.07` also i've checked temp and i couldn't find a file called `ns*` - unless you meant * to indicate version or something else, in that case i found 
`~ nsu.tmp`
`nssB609.tmp`
`nsi5309.tmp`
all of which folders unfortunately not containing the liscense - i have also tried it with  a random link `https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt` and that didn't work either

Comment: Yes, a subfolder named ns... in %temp%. If the file is not there you are doing something wrong or there is a problem with your inetc plug-in. Maybe you put the wrong Unicode/Ansi plug-in in the wrong NSIS plug-in folder?

Comment: Ok, thankyou [@Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501/anders) ill check that and turn in for tonight and update this thread in future if i solve it.
thanks again for the help i appreciate it :)